# iOS 16 has more noise in stream of raw depth values

Tags: depth, ios-camera, ios16

I'm having an issue with depth values using iOS 16. I'm getting noisier depth data from my AVFCaptureSession on iOS 16 than iOS 15 and below. Has something changed for iOS 16? If anyone has encountered same issue or know how to resolve? Please advice me.

I'm using the dual wide camera. My session initialization (minus some exception handling for when the session fails to initialize) looks like:

```
let defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice? =
    AVCaptureDevice.default(
        .builtInDualWideCamera, 
        for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back
    )

let videoDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)

session.beginConfiguration()
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080
guard session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else { return }

...

var depthFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
if session.canAddOutput(depthDataOutput) {
    session.addOutput(depthDataOutput)
    depthDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateDepthData = true
    depthDataOutput.isFilteringEnabled = false
    guard let connection = depthDataOutput.connection(with: .depthData) else { return }
    connection.isEnabled = true

    // Search for highest resolution available (by width)
    depthFormat = videoDevice.activeFormat.supportedDepthDataFormats.filter({
        kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat32
        == CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType($0.formatDescription)
    }).max(by: {
        fmt1, fmt2 in
        CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(fmt1.formatDescription).width
          < CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(fmt2.formatDescription).width
    })
}
...
session.commitConfiguration()
```